# What exactly are the relpages of a postgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to work myself deeper into PostgreSQL and I stumbled over the *relation pages* of a table. I just can't wrap my head around this and I can't find any explanation of what they really are.

My guess would be: A table is kinda chunked into these pages? I know that by default a page is 8 kb, so I would say that a page is an 8 kb data chunk on the disk of the table.

Is that right? Or am I completely wrong on this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html

Comment: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/pgday-160706194137/95/nine-circles-of-inferno-or-explaining-the-postgresql-vacuum-7-638.jpg?cb=1492338315

Comment: @nos: I guess Andwari refers to the column `relpages` in [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is right and thanks for that link, that explains it and confirms my guess! Somehow I didn't come over that page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are quite right.
A table is called a relation (terminology from the "ER" model - the academic/theoretical background for RDBMS...) - so relpages are just that - pages containing the relation data.

the idea behind this is to provide area of continuous disk space for the table (for better performance) while still maintaining flexibility in the allocation and on disk placement of data.